# Textsuperscript and linebreak problem

Tags: line-breaking, citing, natbib, superscripts

I got a problem when doing cites and linebreaks. 
I configured `natbib` the following way:

```
\usepackage{babelbib} 
\usepackage[super,square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

Now, citing multiple references inside text:

> ...Weise auch modulatorische Aktivität für das Aktin-Cytoskelett, weswegen gelegentlich eine Art Netzwerk-Cross-Talk (engl. für
>   Übersprechen) diskutiert
>   wird\cite{wu:par1mappsd,kodama:acf7microtubuli,tsvetkov:claspsmicrotubuli,jaworski:microtubuledynamicsspines,hoogenraad:microtubulispines}.
>   Bestätigend dazu zeigte eine Studie zum mikrotubuli assoziierten
>   Protein 1B (MAP1b), dass dessen Knockout in Mäusen die Hippocampale
>   Spine-Dichte reduzierte. Dies...

This produces the cite in brackets superscripted. Looks nice, if it wouldn't run over the page width:

[image: using super option]

Now, if I remove the super-option from `\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}` it breakes the lines as usual:

[image: using no super option]

So it's the super-option which makes the text running over the page width. Now I tried the `\textsuperscript` command and entered a pretty large text:

> ...Spine-Dichte reduzierte. Dies wurde zusammen mit RhoA-Aktivierung
>   und Rac1-Inaktivierung beobachtet, also Modulatoren der
>   Aktin-dynamik\cite{tortosa:map1bspinematuration}.\textsuperscript{test
>   test test test test test test te-st test test test test}\ Andere
>   Beispiele, die zunächst über eine Veränderung im Transkriptom eine
>   Änderung...

Also here, the superscript text runs over the page width:

[image]

Finally, here is my preamble:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,BCOR8mm,DIV=calc,oneside,headings=normal,parskip=half,toc=graduated,bibliography=totocnumbered,final]{scrreprt}
    \pagestyle{headings}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{frutigernext}
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % andere schriftart

    \usepackage{setspace} % um Zeilenabstand definieren zu kÃ¶nnen
    \usepackage[left=30mm, right=29mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,bindingoffset=8mm]{geometry} %RÃ¤nder
    \usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} % Deutsche Trennungen, Anführungsstriche und mehr, englisch in den Zitaten
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % Eingabe von ä,ö,ü,ß erlauben
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{4} % TOC wird bis auf Ebene 4 herunter gestellt
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

    \usepackage[markuppercase,clines]{scrpage2} % fÃ¼r die Striche in den Kopf- und FuÃŸzeilen
    \clearscrheadfoot
    \renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}
    % Kopfzeile
    \chead[]{}
    \automark{chapter}
    \ihead[\headmark]{\uppercase{\headmark}}
    \ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
    \setheadsepline{0.5pt}


    % ----- BIBTEX -----
    \usepackage{babelbib} % Deutsche Zitierweise, muss nach(!!!) babel geladen werden
    \usepackage[super,square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib} % fÃ¼r die Zitate: Nummer in eckigen Klammern, hochgestellt


    % ----- MISC -----
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{lscape} % stellenweises Querformat
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{pifont}% Symbole einfügen \ding{i}
    \usepackage{url} % zum intelligenten anzeigen von url's
    \usepackage{amsmath} % mathematische Formel einbinden
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{textcomp} %für Textzeichen wie TM, (c), (R)
    \usepackage{upgreek}


    % ----- GRAFIKEN -----
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{graphicx} % zum Einbinden von Grafiken
    \setcapindent{0pt}
    \addtokomafont{caption}{\footnotesize}
    \addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
    \usepackage{wrapfig} %für umfließen von grafiken / tabellen
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage[absolute]{textpos} 


    % ----- FARBEN -----
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage[table,usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}


    % ----- TABELLEN -----
    \usepackage{tabu}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{calc}
    \newcommand{\ctabukopf}{\taburowcolors[1]1{gray!100 .. gray!100}\rowfont[c]\bfseries\hline}
    \newcommand{\ltabukopf}{\taburowcolors[1]1{gray!100 .. gray!100}\rowfont[l]\bfseries\hline}
    \newcommand{\tabudashedline}{\tabucline[on 2pt gray!100]}
    \newlength{\quotetextwidth}
    \setlength{\quotetextwidth}{\textwidth-\leftmargin}


    % ----- SOURCECODE -----
    \usepackage{listings} % Source-Code printer fÃ¼r LaTeX
    \usepackage{etoolbox} %entfernt "closed-bracked-bug


    % ----- REFS, FOOTNOTES -----
    \usepackage{prettyref}
    \usepackage{titleref}
    % text:
    \newrefformat{sec}{siehe Abschnitt~\ref{#1} auf Seite \pageref{#1}}
    \newrefformat{insec}{siehe auch Er\"orterungen auf Seite \pageref{#1}}
    \newcommand{\prettysections}[2]{siehe auch Abschnitt~\ref{#1} \glqq\titleref{#1}\grqq \ auf Seite \pageref{#1} und Abschnitt~\ref{#2} \glqq\titleref{#2}\grqq \ auf Seite \pageref{#2}}
    \newcommand{\prettysection}[1]{siehe auch Abschnitt~\ref{#1} \glqq\titleref{#1}\grqq \ auf Seite \pageref{#1}}
    \newcommand{\prettyfig}[1]{siehe auch Abbildung~\ref{#1}\ auf Seite \pageref{#1}}
    \newcommand{\prettyqsecs}[2]{siehe Abschnitt~\ref{#1}\ auf Seite \pageref{#1}\ und Abschnitt~\ref{#2}\ auf Seite \pageref{#2}}
    \newcommand{\prettyqsec}[1]{siehe Abschnitt~\ref{#1}\ auf Seite \pageref{#1}}

    \usepackage[para]{footmisc} 
    \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\rule{0pt}{0pt}} %ausblenden der linie
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\normalsize\fnsymbol{footnote}}
    % figs:
    \newrefformat{fig}{siehe Abbildung~\ref{#1} \glqq\titleref{#1}\grqq \ auf Seite \pageref{#1}}
    % tabs:
    \newrefformat{tab}{siehe Tabelle~\ref{#1} \glqq\titleref{#1}\grqq \ auf Seite \pageref{#1}}
```

---

Of course I can provide you with a minimal example - I should have added it in my initial post:

test.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,BCOR8mm,DIV=calc,oneside,headings=normal,parskip=half,toc=graduated,bibliography=totocnumbered,final]{scrreprt}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace} % um Zeilenabstand definieren zu kÃ¶nnen
\usepackage[left=30mm, right=29mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,bindingoffset=8mm]{geometry} %RÃ¤nder
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} % Deutsche Trennungen, Anführungsstriche und mehr, englisch in den Zitaten
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % Eingabe von ä,ö,ü,ß erlauben
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} % TOC wird bis auf Ebene 4 herunter gestellt
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage[markuppercase,clines]{scrpage2} % fÃ¼r die Striche in den Kopf- und FuÃŸzeilen
\clearscrheadfoot
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}
% Kopfzeile
\chead[]{}
\automark{chapter}
\ihead[\headmark]{\uppercase{\headmark}}
\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\setheadsepline{0.5pt}


% ----- BIBTEX -----
\usepackage{babelbib} % Deutsche Zitierweise, muss nach(!!!) babel geladen werden
\usepackage[super,square,numbers]{natbib} % fÃ¼r die Zitate: Nummer in eckigen Klammern, hochgestellt


% ----- MISC -----
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lscape} % stellenweises Querformat
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pifont}% Symbole einfügen \ding{i}
\usepackage{url} % zum intelligenten anzeigen von url's
\usepackage{amsmath} % mathematische Formel einbinden
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp} %für Textzeichen wie TM, (c), (R)
\usepackage{upgreek}


% ----- GRAFIKEN -----
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx} % zum Einbinden von Grafiken
\setcapindent{0pt}
\addtokomafont{caption}{\footnotesize}
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\usepackage{wrapfig} %für umfließen von grafiken / tabellen
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos} 


% ----- FARBEN -----
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table,usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}


% ----- TABELLEN -----
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\ctabukopf}{\taburowcolors[1]1{gray!100 .. gray!100}\rowfont[c]\bfseries\hline}
\newcommand{\ltabukopf}{\taburowcolors[1]1{gray!100 .. gray!100}\rowfont[l]\bfseries\hline}
\newcommand{\tabudashedline}{\tabucline[on 2pt gray!100]}
\newlength{\quotetextwidth}
\setlength{\quotetextwidth}{\textwidth-\leftmargin}


% ----- SOURCECODE -----
\usepackage{listings} % Source-Code printer fÃ¼r LaTeX
\usepackage{etoolbox} %entfernt "closed-bracked-bug


% ----- REFS, FOOTNOTES -----
\usepackage{prettyref}
\usepackage{titleref}
% text:
\newrefformat{sec}{siehe Abschnitt~\ref{#1} auf Seite \pageref{#1}}
\newrefformat{insec}{siehe auch Er\"orterungen auf Seite \pageref{#1}}
\newcommand{\prettysections}[2]{siehe auch Abschnitt~\ref{#1} \glqq\titleref{#1}\grqq \ auf Seite \pageref{#1} und Abschnitt~\ref{#2} \glqq\titleref{#2}\grqq \ auf Seite \pageref{#2}}
\newcommand{\prettysection}[1]{siehe auch Abschnitt~\ref{#1} \glqq\titleref{#1}\grqq \ auf Seite \pageref{#1}}
\newcommand{\prettyfig}[1]{siehe auch Abbildung~\ref{#1}\ auf Seite \pageref{#1}}
\newcommand{\prettyqsecs}[2]{siehe Abschnitt~\ref{#1}\ auf Seite \pageref{#1}\ und Abschnitt~\ref{#2}\ auf Seite \pageref{#2}}
\newcommand{\prettyqsec}[1]{siehe Abschnitt~\ref{#1}\ auf Seite \pageref{#1}}

\usepackage[para]{footmisc} 
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\rule{0pt}{0pt}} %ausblenden der linie
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\normalsize\fnsymbol{footnote}}
% figs:
\newrefformat{fig}{siehe Abbildung~\ref{#1} \glqq\titleref{#1}\grqq \ auf Seite \pageref{#1}}
% tabs:
\newrefformat{tab}{siehe Tabelle~\ref{#1} \glqq\titleref{#1}\grqq \ auf Seite \pageref{#1}}

    \begin{document}
    \selectlanguage{ngerman}
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
    \onehalfspacing
    \chapter{CITE-MWE}
    \subsection{something}
    ...Weise auch modulatorische Aktivität für das Aktin-Cytoskelett, weswegen gelegentlich eine Art Netzwerk-Cross-Talk (engl. für Übersprechen) diskutiert\cite{a:a,a:c,a:d,a:f,a:h,a:j,a:b,a:e,a:g,a:i} wird. Bestätigend dazu zeigte eine Studie zum mikrotubuli assoziierten Protein 1B (MAP1b), dass dessen Knockout in Mäusen die Hippocampale Spine-Dichte reduzierte. Dies...
    \clearpage


    \chapter{Textsuperscript-MWE}
    \subsection{something}
    ...Weise auch modulatorische Aktivität für das Aktin-Cytoskelett, weswegen gelegentlich eine Art Netzwerk-Cross-Talk (engl. für Übersprechen) diskutiert wird. \textsuperscript{Bestätigend dazu zeigte eine Studie zum mikrotubuli assoziierten Protein 1B (MAP1b), dass dessen Knockout in Mäusen die Hippocampale Spine-Dichte reduzierte.} Dies...
    \clearpage



    %------------------Literatur
    %\bibliographystyle{babunsrt} % Zitierordnung und Stil
    \bibliographystyle{my-plain}
    \setbtxfallbacklanguage{english} % wenn im bib-Eintrag nicht explizit language=[ngerman} gesetzt ist, wird von einem englischen Zitat ausgegangen
    \let\oldbibliography\thebibliography
    \renewcommand{\thebibliography}[1]{%
        \oldbibliography{#1}%
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    }

    \scriptsize
    \bibliography{Quellen}
    \normalsize
    \clearpage

    \end{document}
```

Quellen.bib:

```
@Article{
a:a,
   Author="Garey, L. J.  and Ong, W. Y.  and Patel, T. S.  and Kanani, M.  and Davis, A.  and Mortimer, A. M.  and Barnes, T. R.  and Hirsch, S. R. ",
   Title="{{R}educed dendritic spine density on cerebral cortical pyramidal neurons in schizophrenia}",
   Journal="J. Neurol. Neurosurg. Psychiatr.",
   Year="1998",
   Volume="65",
   Number="4",
   Pages="446--453",
   Month="Oct"
}

@Article{
a:b,
   Author="Lee, F. H.  and Kaidanovich-Beilin, O.  and Roder, J. C.  and Woodgett, J. R.  and Wong, A. H. ",
   Title="{{G}enetic inactivation of {G}{S}{K}3-alpha rescues spine deficits in {D}isc1-{L}100{P} mutant mice}",
   Journal="Schizophr. Res.",
   Year="2011",
   Volume="129",
   Number="1",
   Pages="74--79",
   Month="Jun"
}

@Article{
a:c,
   Author="He, C. X.  and Portera-Cailliau, C. ",
   Title="{{T}he trouble with spines in fragile {X} syndrome: density, maturity and plasticity}",
   Journal="Neuroscience",
   Year="2012",
   Pages=" ",
   Month="Apr"
}

@Article{
a:d,
   Author="Fiala, J. C.  and Spacek, J.  and Harris, K. M. ",
   Title="{{D}endritic spine pathology: cause or consequence of neurological disorders?}",
   Journal="Brain Res. Brain Res. Rev.",
   Year="2002",
   Volume="39",
   Number="1",
   Pages="29--54",
   Month="Jun"
}

@Article{
a:e,
   Author="Penzes, P.  and Cahill, M. E.  and Jones, K. A.  and VanLeeuwen, J. E.  and Woolfrey, K. M. ",
   Title="{{D}endritic spine pathology in neuropsychiatric disorders}",
   Journal="Nat. Neurosci.",
   Year="2011",
   Volume="14",
   Number="3",
   Pages="285--293",
   Month="Mar"
}

@Article{
a:f,
   Author="Mines, M. A.  and Jope, R. S. ",
   Title="{{G}lycogen synthase kinase-3: a promising therapeutic target for fragile x syndrome}",
   Journal="Front Mol Neurosci",
   Year="2011",
   Volume="4",
   Pages="35"
}

@Article{
a:g,
   Author="Mines, M. A.  and Jope, R. S. ",
   Title="{{G}lycogen synthase kinase-3: a promising therapeutic target for fragile x syndrome}",
   Journal="Front Mol Neurosci",
   Year="2011",
   Volume="4",
   Pages="35"
}

@Article{
a:h,
   Author="Mines, M. A.  and Jope, R. S. ",
   Title="{{G}lycogen synthase kinase-3: a promising therapeutic target for fragile x syndrome}",
   Journal="Front Mol Neurosci",
   Year="2011",
   Volume="4",
   Pages="35"
}

@Article{
a:i,
   Author="Mines, M. A.  and Jope, R. S. ",
   Title="{{G}lycogen synthase kinase-3: a promising therapeutic target for fragile x syndrome}",
   Journal="Front Mol Neurosci",
   Year="2011",
   Volume="4",
   Pages="35"
}

@Article{
a:j,
   Author="Mines, M. A.  and Jope, R. S. ",
   Title="{{G}lycogen synthase kinase-3: a promising therapeutic target for fragile x syndrome}",
   Journal="Front Mol Neurosci",
   Year="2011",
   Volume="4",
   Pages="35"
}

@Article{
a:k,
   Author="Mines, M. A.  and Jope, R. S. ",
   Title="{{G}lycogen synthase kinase-3: a promising therapeutic target for fragile x syndrome}",
   Journal="Front Mol Neurosci",
   Year="2011",
   Volume="4",
   Pages="35"
}
```

I did not include my-plain.bst. You can download the whole bunch from here: [test.zip](http://homepages-nw.uni-r.de/~ocs23577/test.zip)

Comment: Can you please provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: The whole superscript is set into a box, that will not allow linebreaks within. You have to break manually before or shorten/ enlarge the sentence. Another hint to your citing. I noticed that you cited "... wird[citations]." where it is better (as for your very log citation to cite after the sentence puntuation: "... wird.[citations]" Especially when you use superscripts.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: I've edited in your example, but it's far from minimal. That will make it less likely you'll get an answer: please help us to help you by reducing it to the smallest test case you can.

Comment: @Martin Can you make an answer?

Comment: @egreg I tried to, please feel free to edit/ enhance it. I could not include a bibtex example as I am not familiar with it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not arising due to the citation, but only stems from the uses of superscripts. Whenever superscripts are used, they are intended to be short. Hence line breaks are neither nice nor possible.

The technical reason for this is, that LaTeX will wrap the text given in `\superscript{}` into a box, which is the raised. This box is the treated like any other box. Depending on the given penalties, the line will break before the `superscript` or not at all.

To illustrate this problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} %to show page borders

\begin{document}
%\blindtext

The text in this a paragraph is only to show effectis of superscripting.
No linebreak is allowed in the superscript.
Hence it will extend into the margin.
Dummy text and text for dummies\textsuperscript{see this superscript here}.
And we will continue with even more dummy text.

If you reduce penalties, the line will break before \verb|\textsuperscript|.
This can be done on-the-fly with \verb|\sloppy|. (It is not a nice solution, though.)

\sloppy
The text in this a paragraph is only to show effectis of superscripting.
No linebreak is allowed in the superscript.
Hence it will extend into the margin.
Dummy text and text for dummies\textsuperscript{see this superscript here}.
And we will continue with even more dummy text.

\end{document}
```

This will give:
[image: output]

A rather nasty workaround is to use the `\sloppy` command (or environment).
The more elegant way is to shorten or lengthen the sentence to fit the superscripted section onto the line. An even better way is to try to avoid long superscripts. (As far as I remember, `natbib` comes with a sort+compress option.)

As far as I know, there are no right answers when it comes to citations. 
However, if a citation refers to a phrase in particular, it should follow immediately. If a citation refers to a (half-) sentence, it should be referred after the punctuation.

As far as citations go, I would recommend switching to the `biblatex` package, as it is much more flexible. It also provides the above mentioned behaviour out of the box.

Comment: I've certainly seen styles in the UK which require citations *before* the punctuation at the end of the sentence. biblatex's fondness for putting the punctuation afterwards notwithstanding, it always looks American to me. Not that that is bad if the rest of the typesetting matches but it looks odd if the rest of it is British style!

Comment: @cfr could you give some examples and/or links, I am very curious. As I might have to write some more English soon, that would be of great help.

Comment: I'm afraid the university style guide I had in mind seems to have been updated for 2013/14 and now recommends something completely different. Actually, its recommendations are almost entirely contrary to their previous style guide. This is possibly because the previous version required students to actually make examiners lives more difficult! (Though I'm puzzled by their requirement to use "15pt spacing" since I've no idea what this means. Is this some Word feature?)

Comment: @cfr well that may happen a lot, one can never be sure about 'recommendations'. Usually spacing is dependent on the font size, but in some word processors you can define a fixed spacing between the baselines - maybe that is meant, but I am not sure at all. Thank you for clarification though.